# Sphinx with MySQL configuration

Tags: sphinx

Can I install Sphinx and Mysql in different servers and integrate with one another.

What I have to enter in sphinx.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

No reason they need to be on the same server

Can just specify the hostname(or IP address) of the MySQL server in the sphinx `source` config
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-host

Of course the USER in MySQL will need to allow connections from the sphinx server.